# Draw a circle on Cascades MapView

Tags: blackberry, maps, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'd like to draw a circle over a MapView to show all the points that distance e.g. 20 meters from a point.
I searched on the documentation but I found only ways to draw polygons given a set of coordinates, while I need a way to draw a circle given a point and a radius (in meters).
The Maps app does exactly what I'd like to do when showing signal precision (drawing a cirle around the point, representing precision approximation), so I guess there is a "right way" to do that.

I thought I could write a function to calculate the coordinates of points of the circle from scratch, but it would be difficult to mix longitude/latitude with plain meters...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Acutally it is quite easy using the QGeoCoordinate you can use the [atDistanceAndAzimuth](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qtmobilitysubset__qgeocoordinate.html?f=geocoordinate#function-atdistanceandazimuth-distance-azimuth-distanceup) function to compute all the points on a circle.